# MySQL: Writing log entries from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, logging

Is there a standard way to write log messages in MySQL stored procedures?

I can write [log messages to a designated log table](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/debugging-mysql-stored-procedures/218100564?pgno=2), but I prefer the standard log mechanism where each message is coupled with severity and sent to an external file.